# What's the complement or corollary of "influences"?

Tags: single-word-requests

An article on Wikipedia about a literary work might include a list of *influences*, i.e. a list of earlier works that influenced this one.

What about the other way around – a word for a *later* work that was *influenced by* this one? Is there a noun for that?

Comment: Look at this: [Influence](http://thesaurus.com/browse/influence)

Comment: @SnowFlake - I looked for antonyms in a few thesauruses, including that one. I couldn't find any entry that treats "influence" as a count noun, as in "The album's influences include..."

Comment: Callum,You are right. I am searching for it because it is interesting for me to know too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we were talking about people not books it would be follower or disciple. For a single thing, i.e. the book that takes after an earlier work, I think we need to use either:

1. derivative -- most generally applicable choice
2. sequel -- if it was very contingent or built upon the first
3. offshoot -- if it continues or builds on the first but is not a pure continuation

And based on your edit I think what you are looking for is derivatives or offshoots.

Answer (score 3):

*Follows, derivative, imitative, aping, copying, wannabe, offshoot*. And indeed, "influenced by".

If there are a great many, we may say that it was "in the tradition" of the earlier work, or even that it is part of a *genre* or *movement* that it (alone, or along with contemporaneous works) started. (Or perhaps *founded* if there was a conscious attempt to move in a particular artistic direction).

*Follower, adherent, disciple, imitator, aper, copyist, wannabe & protégé* can all apply to artists who came later, with different nuances as to the relationship to the earlier.

Answer (score 1):

English speakers routinely add prefixes and suffixes to produce words from existing words.
In this situation you can simply produce

> *influencee* from *influence*

to get the meaning you want.

The *-ee* suffix means “the recipient of an action”. It comes from “the Anglo-French *-é* ending of [past participles] used as nouns.” It was originally used when writing law, and is still very commonly used in that context.[¹](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ee)
This is analogous to producing

> *educatee* from *educate*
>   *employee* from *employ*
>   *endorsee* from *endorse*
>   *enlistee* from *enlist*
>   *enrollee* from *enroll*
>   *evictee* from *evict*
>   *examinee* from *examine*
>   *illuminee* from *illumine*
>   *importee* from *import*
>   *indictee* from *indict*
>   *inductee* from *induct*
>   *interrogatee* from *interrogate*
>   *interviewee* from *interview*
>   *invitee* from *invite*

and that is just considering a selection of verbs beginning with *e* and *i*.

Comment: If a person you’ve loved can be said to be one of your beloveds, and one you’ve invited could be said to be one of your inviteds, then I suppose a person you’ve influenced could be said to your influenceds — except for it being so hard to enunciate distinctly.

Answer (score 1):

The noun *[descendant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/descendant#Noun)* is relevant, in its sense  “(figuratively) A thing that derives directly from a given precursor or source [eg]    This famous medieval manuscript has many descendants.”    Also-used is *children*, from senses of *[child](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/child#Noun)* that include  “(figuratively) An offspring” and   “(figuratively) A thing or abstraction derived from or caused by something.”  (For example, the 100+ companies that were offshoots of Fairchild Semiconductor, like AMD and Intel, have been called *Fairchildren*.)

Answer (score 1):

If the influence is very strong, the term *[progeny](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/open?q=open)* may suit

> One born of, begotten by, or derived from another; an offspring or a descendant.